# Как правильно принимать и передавать данные между классами, реализующими части оконного интерфейса?

Tags: c++, qt

В общем, есть примерно такой код (упрощённо):

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

private:
    ..............................
    QSplitter *splitter;
    PhotoWorkArea *work_area;
    ..............................
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}
{
    ..............................
    splitter = new QSplitter{this};
    work_area = new PhotoWorkArea{splitter};
    ..............................
}
```

Я хочу чтобы из `PhotoWorkArea` можно было иметь прямой доступ к другим виджетам, которые включённы в `MainWindow`. Иными словами, мне нужно иметь прямой доступ из одного включённого в `MainWindow` объекта к другим.

Я пытался сделать `PhotoWorkArea` другом `MainWindow` и включить `main_window.hpp` в `photo_work_area.hpp`, но так как второй уже включён в первый, то получается взаимное включение, из-за чего всё ломается. Поэтому единственный вариант, который мне пришёл в голову, включить `main_window.hpp` в `photo_work_area.cpp`, и писать в каждом методе, в котором мне нужен доступ к родительскому (в иерархии `QObject`) `MainWindow` следующее:

```
MainWindow *main_window = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parentWidget()->parentWidget());
```

Всё это как-то костыльно и криво. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать задуманное? Я думаю, что такая проблема не нова, и многие с ней уже сталкивались. Но я не знаю как это можно загуглить.

Comment: Что мешает передать указатель на окно в photoworkarea

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, то, что тип неизветсен внутри PhotoWorkArea.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, кажется, лучше продублировать необходимые поля внутри PhotoWorkArea, добавить сеттеров и геттеров, и вызывать их из слотов MainWondow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришёл к такому выводу. Если нужно из одних частей оконного интерфейса получать и передавать данные в другие части интерфейса, то лучше это делать через слоты MainWindow (или аналога). А вместо дублирования самих данных, создавать внутри классов, реализующих часть оконного интерфейса, поля-указатели на эти данные, и в конструкторе MainWindow передавать их через геттеры и сеттеры соответствующих классов.

**PS:** Но всё же есть более простой, а может быть и более правильный (в зависимсоти от архитектуры приложения), способ:

**child.hpp**

```
#ifndef CHILD_HPP
#define CHILD_HPP

class Parent;

class Child
{
private:
    Parent *parent;

public:
    Child(Parent *parent);
    ~Child() = default;
};

#endif // CHILD_HPP
```

**child.cpp**

```
#include "child.hpp"
#include "parent.hpp"

Child::Child(Parent *_parent) : parent(_parent)
{
    parent->doNothing();
}
```

**parent.hpp**

```
#ifndef PARENT_HPP
#define PARENT_HPP

#include "child.hpp"

class Parent
{
    friend class Child;

private:
    void doNothing() {}

public:
    Parent() = default;
    ~Parent() = default;

private:
    Child child;
};

#endif // PARENT_HPP
```